# Alter field after instantiation in Pydantic BaseModel class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

With a Pydantic class as follows, I want to transform the `foo` field by applying a `replace` operation:

```py
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    foo: List[str]

my_object = MyModel(foo="hello-there")
my_object.foo = [s.replace("-", "_") for s in my_object.foo]
```

How can I do the `replace` operation right within the class, when the object is created? Without Pydantic I would simply do that within `__init(self, foo)` but since Pydantic creates its own `__init__` implementation I'm not sure how to proceed exactly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Using a pydantic BaseModel

It seems as you would have to override the basemodels init method, something like this:

```py
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    foo: List[str]

    def __init__(self, **data):
        data["foo"] = [s.replace("-", "_") for s in data["foo"]]
        super().__init__(**data)

my_object = MyModel(foo=["hello-there"])

print(my_object)
# Outputs foo=['hello_there']
```

### Using a Pydantic dataclass

... or you could also turn it into a pydantic dataclass and use the post init dunder provided by pydantic to do other things upon instantiation. e.g:

```py
from typing import List
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyModel():
    foo: List[str]

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.foo = [s.replace("-", "_") for s in self.foo]

my_object = MyModel(foo=["hello-there"])

print(my_object)

# Outputs foo=['hello_there']
```

Answer (score 18):

### Pydantic version 2.0+

According to the [documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/api/main/#pydantic.main.BaseModel.model_post_init), this is the syntax:

```py
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: str
    
    def model_post_init(self, __context) -> None:
        values = self.dict()
        # manipulation on fields
```

Answer (score 16):

Use the `@validator` decorator (in this case with the option `each_item=True`, since we want the validator to look at each item in the list rather than the list itself):

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    foo: List[str]

    @validator('foo', each_item=True)
    def replace_hyphen(cls,v):
        return v.replace("-","_")

my_object = MyModel(foo=["hello-there"])

print(my_object)
# Outputs foo=['hello_there']
```

or if you prefer dataclasses:

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import validator
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyModelDC():
    foo: List[str]

    @validator('foo', each_item=True)
    def replace_hyphen(cls,v):
        return v.replace("-","_")

my_objectDC = MyModelDC(foo=["hello-there"])

print(my_objectDC)
# Outputs foo=['hello_there']
```

Comment: really nice. The `each_item=True` bit sounds a bit too "dark magic" but still quite handy.